# Bootstrap Datatables pagination and sorting

Tags: ajax, jsp, datatables

I'm using **datatables** and **bootstrap** for pagination but its not working.

The data is received via **ajax** ,as soon as i press any header to sort the table, the data dissappears.

The html for table itself

```
        <table id="tablePersonnel"
            class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0"
            width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Phone number</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Phone number</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            
        </table>
```

here is the javascript for the function responsible for getting the data

```
refreshTable = function() {
    $
            .ajax({
                url : "listPersonnel",
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(response) {
                    data = response;
                    var no = 1;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $("#tablePersonnel")
                                .append(
                                        '<tr> <td>'
                                                + data[i].id
                                                + '</td> <td>'
                                                + data[i].firstname
                                                + '</td> <td>'
                                                + data[i].name
                                                + '</td> <td>'
                                                + data[i].phone
                                                + '</td> <td>'
                                                + data[i].status
                                                + '</td><td><input type="button" class="btn1" onclick="openEditPopup('
                                                + i
                                                + ')" value="Edit"></input></td> <td> <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="openDeletePopup('
                                                + i
                                                + ');" value=""><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td> </tr>');
                        no = no + 1;
                    }
                
                    
                }
            });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach involves adding data to the HTML table (i.e. to the DOM). However, the DataTables object does not know about this data - which is why the data disappears whenever you perform any action which involves a DataTables refresh. DataTables is showing you its data - which is no data.

Instead, you can perform your ajax call from within DataTables itself - and then DataTables will handle the data for you.

I will assume the JSON returned by your ajax call has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "firstname": "Tom",
    "name": "Smith",
    "phone": "121-212-1212",
    "status": "foo"
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "name": "Jones",
    "phone": "434-545=6767",
    "status": "bar"
  }
]
```

In that case, you can use the following table HTML:

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And your DataTable configuration will be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      "ajax": { 
        "url": "listPersonnel",
        "dataSrc": ''
      },
      "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "firstname" },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "phone" },
        { "data": "status" },
        { "data": function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
          var content = '<input type="button" class="btn1" onclick="openEditPopup('
              + row.id
              + ')" value="Edit"></input></td> <td> <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="openDeletePopup('
              + row.id
              + ');" value=""><i class="fa fa-trash">trash</i></button>'
          return content;
        } }
      ]

    } );

  } );

</script>
```

The result looks like this (I don't have your trash icon):

[image]

Points to note:

There is no iteration logic here - it's handled for you by DataTables, as it consumes your JSON response.

If your JSON has a different structure, you will need to adjust the above. Examples of different approaches are shown [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/).

In your case, we use `dataSrc = ''` because your JSON is an array of objects - and it does not have a container object.

The data in the final column is generated via a function which builds the string you need.

You can define column headings directly in DataTable also, instead of in the HTML.

There are many variations on this approach - DataTables has a lot of flexibility.